# Facebook SDK (canvas) get user picture

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am making a facebook canvas application and i want to get the user's picture. i tried to do that:

```js
FB.api(
    "/{user-id}/picture",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    }
);
```

and then look for the output in the console but it doesnt console.log anything. what should i do?

Comment: Just do <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/picture">

Comment: **Thank You! Works Great!**